# how to change double key stroke rate ubuntu 12.04

Tags: keyboard

I am an absolute newbie and struggling with Ubuntu! I am using Unity on 12.04 and where possible prefer to use GUI controls rather than terminal.
In  I can alter the repeat rate when a key is held down but can find no way to change the delay when repeating a key stroke as when typing double letters (allow, see. etc) At the moment I have to wait about 0.5sec before I can type the repeated letter! How can I speed this up? 
Have checked many other answers in the forums but cannot find this question.

Comment: Have you checked `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Typing` and tried changing the 'Repeat keys' values? I've never changed any keyboard settings and I don't have the half-second delay you describe. (You access the settings by clicking the little gear icon, very top right of the screen.) Note there are two different options for keyboard settings in that first menu, 'Keyboard layout' and 'Keyboard'. You want the second one.

Comment: @TomYes, as I said I have already tried changing the settings in 'keyboard' for both delay and speed

Answer (score 4):

I used xset. The following will show the current *Repeat Rate Delay* and the *Repeat Rate*:

```
xset q
```

My default values were 200,33. The following will set the repeat rates:

```
xset r rate 500 33
```

The *Repeat Rate Delay* refers to the time it takes for a 2nd repeat character to appear when a character key is pressed down.

The *Repeat Rate* refers to the delay between the next repeat character to be displayed after the repeat rate delay has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following line:

```
xset r rate 500 33
```

This will fix your problems,  trust me. It fixed mine

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Universal Access -> Typing -> Typing Assist(Access X) and turn off Bounce keys if it is on.